# XML is not read fully by SSIS package

Tags: xml, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to read XML files in SSIS package. The thing is that when I'm trying to read XML source file using XML SOURCE process it doesn't read full content of this file. In my scenario I have some files in folder which I read using "For Each Loop". Then when I need to map colums available in this file I don't see one property : "Date_of_adding" what is very important for me also. I have read that I should divide XML reading in two parts and later join result of each path into one result but I can't do that : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ca7dabf5-9810-4661-b8cb-94c2fd0fddde/loading-xml-file-with-header-and-detail-information-to-sql-sever-table?forum=sqlintegrationservices. Can you help me and tell how to read missing level? I have following components already created:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

Comment: "I should divide XML reading in two parts and later join result of each path into one result but I can't do that" why not? Are you getting an error? the XML Source component has several outputs, depending on your XSD hierarchy, make sure that the one that is linked to your Data Conversion is the "Table Currency" one.

Comment: The problem is, that in COLUMNS subtab I don't have posibility to choose interesting output, only have elements from position. Why I can't see more outputs of this XML? What is wrong here?

Comment: Delete the line that links your XML source with the Data Conversion, then click on the XML Source to select it and drag and drop a new link to the Data Conversion. A display should pop up asking which output of the XML you want to link (table currency or position). These are the nested levels of your XML (as stated in the XSD).

Comment: I have performed your steps and haven't got any pop up asking me for which level I want to choose. Still got the same result - "POSITION" elements only. Can you assist?

Comment: XSD file is attached above. There is column in this file but it doesn't show up as a separate level in XML task output level. That's the problem here.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think the two items <number_of_table> and <date_of_adding> are not at a correct position either in the xsd or in the xml... if possible, try moving it - within the xsd - before the xs:complex_type or at least before the xs:sequence AFTER table_currency

Comment: Okay, so the thing now is: I moved for testing this <date_of_adding> inside some fake new node. It sees this but I can't do this operations because I download dynamically about 30 files into disk and then need to insert them in table. The structure is the same in all files and I can't change it.

Comment: Therefore you should modify the xsd and not the xml.... you might even want to try the "use inline schema" for a try... and I guess there is even the possibility to generate a XSD from a example file...

Comment: Okay, I the XSD file is created from this downloaded files. I haven't manipulated anything inside it and assume that it should see every possible level. This XSD file is attached above in my photo. Where should then I move this node?

Comment: Not a separate node but only the two lines with name="number_of_table" and name="date_of_adding" and I would try to place them either directly after line 3 (name="table_currency") or after line 4 (xs:complexType)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170627/discussion-between-tyron78-and-dkm).

Comment: @DKM Did you find a solution? If not, I managed to define some C# code you could use as Source...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining a C# script component as source - this provides the possibility to handle the XML as required without the hassle of using a XSD. Anyways, if it comes to way more complex XML scripts, an additional XSLT would be usefull.
However, following an example C# console app code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start...");

            string sPath = "C:\\temp\\xs\\a.xml";

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sPath);

            string snumer_tabeli = xdoc.Element("tabela_kursow").Element("numer_tabeli").Value.ToString();
            string sdata_publikacji = xdoc.Element("tabela_kursow").Element("data_publikacji").Value.ToString();

            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xdoc.Element("tabela_kursow").Elements("pozycja");
            foreach (XElement element in elements)
            {
                // Start of SSIS Buffer Column adding...
                Console.WriteLine("numer_tabeli ---> " + snumer_tabeli);
                Console.WriteLine("data_publikacji ---> " + sdata_publikacji);
                foreach (XElement xelement in element.Descendants())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xelement.Name + " ---> " + xelement.Value.ToString());
                }
                // End of SSIS Buffer Column adding...
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("...End");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And here an example SSIS script component.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sPath);

    string snumer_tabeli = xdoc.Element("tabela_kursow").Element("numer_tabeli").Value.ToString();
    string sdata_publikacji = xdoc.Element("tabela_kursow").Element("data_publikacji").Value.ToString();

    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xdoc.Element("tabela_kursow").Elements("pozycja");
    foreach (XElement element in elements)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.numertabeli = snumer_tabeli;
        Output0Buffer.datapublikacji = sdata_publikacji;
        foreach (XElement xelement in element.Descendants())
        {
            switch (xelement.Name.ToString())
            {
                case "nazwa_waluty":
                    Output0Buffer.nazwawaluty = xelement.Value.ToString();
                    break;

                case "przelicznik":
                    Output0Buffer.przelicznik = xelement.Value.ToString();
                    break;

                case "kod_waluty":
                    Output0Buffer.kodwaluty = xelement.Value.ToString();
                    break;

                case "kurs_sredni":
                    Output0Buffer.kurssredni = xelement.Value.ToString();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sPath is a variable I defined and which I loaded from a SSIS package variable. In order to use this component, you have to add a reference to System.XML.Linq to the script component. And for the time being, I defined ALL output columns as String (dt_wstr(50) - you will have to take care of transformations either within the script or in the next task in your dataflow.

Comment: Thank you. Solution in my case is as follows: I have  used XPATH to get this one value from <date_of_adding>  tag and saved it to global variable. Next, I have read this <position> tags using XML control available in SSIS and later joined it with "Derived column" control and put everything into database. It works fine. Every iteration of For each loop this variable is changed and joined with new elements from new read file. It works fine.

Comment: OK. Good approach, even if I prefer solving it in one step over two steps and derived column. ;-) But as long as it works its all right :-D

Answer (score 1):

Hm, interesting case.
Basically, you have a `table currency` root element and not being able to read its properties - `date of adding`.
SSIS **XML Source** derives set of outputs from the XML structure and the top level entry is not mapped to any output; this is by design. Some explanations of this phenomena are given at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140277.aspx).
The solution I used in similar cases - add another root node before `table currency` node, so your XML will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root_node>
 <table_currency ...>
 ...
 </table_currency>
</root_node>
```

You can perform this with **XML Task** using XSLT transform like this

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <root_node>
  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
 </root_node>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I did something similar but not adding root element but some other later in xml. I moved those two nodes into new one and it recognized this change after I updated XSD file. Problem is that I cannot do this because I download every time dynamically from HTTP source. This is good but cannot be done here in my solution . Now it works after I did everything described above in a comment. THanks for info here.